# Problems adapting my app from tabs (activity) to tabs with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have not worked that much with Android development so that's why I ask for your help. I previously implemented tabs to my app via different activities and everything was working fine.

Now or I wanted to have swipe gesture working I switched to tabs with fragments. this was working fine until I ran out of memory with some of activities that are started from these tabs. Is there something really wrong in my MainMenuActivity or is the problem in fragments or in layout files?

I use min API 10 and have implemented android-support-v7-appcompat in my app.

Here is my MainmenuActivity.java

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";

     private ViewPager viewPager;
     private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
     private ActionBar actionBar;
     // Tab titles
     private String[] tabs = { "Team", "League", "You", "Office" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu_lay);


            // Initilization
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

            // Adding Tabs
            for (String tab_name : tabs) {
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                        .setTabListener(this));
            }       

        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });    

    }    

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // Restore the previously serialized current tab position.
      if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
        getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      // Serialize the current tab position.
      outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getSupportActionBar()
          .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

And here is the code I use to open up new activities from fragments.

```
public void DisplayTraining(){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), TrainingActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

The errors that shows up in LogCat are listed below

```
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fc.manager14/com.fc.manager14.StadiumActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at com.fc.manager14.StadiumActivity.onCreate(StadiumActivity.java:37)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  ... 11 more
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  ... 25 more
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:498)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:473)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
02-12 19:48:06.512: E/AndroidRuntime(456):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
```

Comment: Which line corresponds to your 37th line in your StadiumActivity file?

Comment: 37th line in StadiumActivity is: setContentView(R.layout.stadium_lay);

Comment: I use SherlockFragmentActivity. Take a look http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Exception is being generated in the `setContentView()` instruction, which inflates your layout and afterwards you have a Out of Memory error. That's probably because there is some drawable(s) within your layout that are taking too much memory to render.

If you say that when you used an `Activity` instead everything was ok, I'd start removing all drawables and start putting one by one again seeing what happens, this way you'll be able to see there the bottleneck is.

This doesn't mean if can be just for some drawables size, though. Maybe your `Fragment` is being started many times when it shouldn't, so additionally put some `Log.d()` lines to control it and you'll find out where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I used Log.d() and found out that when swiping between tabs, fragments are being created again and again... Any idea how to stop this? Should I use detach and attach? Any sample code is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using the `detach()/attach()` approach, since using them doesn't make them destroy, just keep them and don't recreate them. I can't provide an example now since I'm not at home, but it's easy to find some (try searching by `vogella fragments`)